# Terraform expression for_each invalid index

Tags: terraform

HI Guys and happy new year to all

I got an issue to gatter the token generate by the bloc ressource below which have an iteration with an for_each loop.

my varibale map is :

```
 variable "wvd_hostpool" {
 description = "Please provide the required information to create a WVD hostpool."
 type        = map(any)
 default = {
   hp-azcan-weu-wvd-01 = {
     "name"                             = "hp-azcan-weu-wvd-01"
     "type"                             = "Personal"
     "load_balancer_type"               = "DepthFirst"
     "personal_desktop_assignment_type" = "Automatic"
     "maximum_sessions_allowed"         = 16
     "expiration_date"                  = "2022-02-10T18:46:43Z"
     "friendly_name"                    = "Canary"
     "description"                      = "Dedicated to canary deployments."
     "location"                         = "westeurope"
     "vm_count"                         = 1
     "vm_size"                          = "Standard_F4s_v2"
     "vm_prefix"                        = "AZWEUHP01TST"
     "validate_environment"             = "true"
   },
   hp-azprd-weu-wvd-01 = {
     "name"                             = "hp-azprd-weu-wvd-01"
     "type"                             = "Pooled"
     "load_balancer_type"               = "DepthFirst"
     "personal_desktop_assignment_type" = "Automatic"
     "maximum_sessions_allowed"         = 16
     "expiration_date"                  = "2022-02-10T18:46:43Z"
     "friendly_name"                    = "desktop"
     "description"                      = "Dedicated to medium workload type (Microsoft Word, CLIs, ...)."
     "location"                         = "westeurope"
     "vm_count"                         = 1
     "vm_size"                          = "Standard_F4s_v2"
     "vm_prefix"                        = "AZWEUHP01WKT"
     "validate_environment"             = "false"
   },
```

the ressource bloc :

```
  resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "wvd_hostpool" {
  for_each                         = var.wvd_hostpool
  name                             = each.value.name
  location                         = each.value.location
  custom_rdp_properties            = "audiocapturemode:i:1;audiomode:i:0;"
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.avd_rg.name
  validate_environment             = each.value.validate_environment
  type                             = each.value.type
  load_balancer_type               = each.value.load_balancer_type
  friendly_name                    = each.value.friendly_name
  description                      = each.value.description
  personal_desktop_assignment_type = each.value.personal_desktop_assignment_type
  maximum_sessions_allowed         = each.value.maximum_sessions_allowed

  registration_info {
    expiration_date = each.value.expiration_date
  }
}
```

I would get the value of the token generate under registration_info to save it to a key vault for reuse or export it to an output but  has you can see I getting an error with invalid index. I speding 2 day without sucess at this could you help me please ?

```
  resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "wvd_registration_info" {
  for_each     = var.wvd_hostpool
  name         = each.value.name
  value        = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool[each.value.name].registration_info.0.token
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.wvd_key_vault.id
  depends_on   = [azurerm_role_assignment.wvd_sp]
}
```

the same result

```
Error: Invalid index
│
│   on security.tf line 115, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "wvd_registration_info":
│  115:   value        = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool[each.value.name].registration_info[0].token
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool is object with 3 attributes
│     │ each.value.name is "hp-azprd-weu-wvd-02"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no elements
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a map as a `for_each` attribute, Terraform will use its keys as identifiers for the resources which will be created. This means that if you want to reference a another resource created using a `for_each`, you have to use they keys from the map, or `each.key` in your example:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "wvd_registration_info" {
  for_each     = var.wvd_hostpool
  name         = each.value.name
  value        = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool[each.key].registration_info.token
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.wvd_key_vault.id
  depends_on   = [azurerm_role_assignment.wvd_sp]
}
```

Comment: I seem it's what I did it's the value of each name of var.wvd_hostpool.with the each key. I get the same error

Comment: Ervin I just update the variable to shwo your more informations about it but with the kay it's not possible I need the token of each azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool

Comment: I think this `azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool[each.key].registration_info.0.token`  is not correct, you may want to have it like this `azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool[each.key].registration_info.token`. Updated my answer.

Comment: he need the index for the token if this can help I do a terraform console to export the result of azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool

Comment: and register info is a list  `"hp-azprd-weu-wvd-02" = {
    "registration_info" = tolist([])`

Comment: also the result of the terraform plan give this `azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool["hp-azprd-weu-wvd-02"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "wvd_hostpool" {
      ~ id                               = "/subscriptions//resourceGroups/rg-tst-weu-avd-01/providers/Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostPools/hp-azprd-weu-wvd-02" 
      + registration_info {
          + expiration_date = "2022-02-10T18:46:43Z"
          + reset_token     = (known after apply)
          + token           = (sensitive value) `

Comment: here the result of what you send to me  `Error: Unsupported attribute
│   on security.tf line 115, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "wvd_registration_info":
│  115:   value        = "${azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool[each.key].registration_info.token}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.wvd_hostpool is object with 3 attributes
│     │ each.key is "hp-azprd-weu-wvd-01"
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "token" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?`